# no spaces between fonts and unnecessary bold font

Tags: beamer, math-mode, spacing, setspace, boldsymbol

[image]

```
\documentclass[svgnames,A4paper,8pt]{beamer} % dvipsnames gives more built-in colors
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usetheme{Ilmenau}
\useoutertheme{miniframes} % Alternatively: miniframes, infolines, split
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\definecolor{UBCblue}{rgb}{0.04706, 0.13725, 0.26667} % UBC Blue (primary)

\usecolortheme[named=UBCblue]{structure}


\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\begin{frame}[t]\vspace{4pt}

  \begin{block}{Logistic regression(to estimate the likelihood of choosing for solid fuel by the households)}
\vspace{0.5em}
\scriptsize Let be the conditional mean \psi and dependent variable Y given explanatory variable X, $\Pr(Y \mid X)$) 
\begin{itemize}
    \item{}
    \item{Sample size: 22,126}

\end{itemize}
\end{block}
\end{frame}
```

Comment: You can highlight your code and click `{}` to format it.  But could you also say what your question is?

Comment: Don't ignore errors. `\psi` is a math-mode macro.

Comment: @campa Thanks. I needed to use $\psi$

Comment: Unrelated to the error: instead of passing the `svgnames` to all packages, write `xcolor={svgnames}` to only pass it to the package you want. The option `A4paper` is a) called `a4paper` and b) makes no sense in beamer as beamer uses a custom paper format.

Comment: `\item` does not take an argument, instead of `\item{...}` you should write `\item ...`

Comment: The weirdness with the bold seems to be the result of the variant of Computer Modern Sans that gets loaded when you use `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}`, which doesn't allow the full range of font sizes, and so when you use both `8pt` in the document class options and `\scriptsize` at the same time, it ends up using a different, bold, font. You could load the `fix-cm` package to fix this and similar issues: `\usepackage{fix-cm}`. (Or switch to a different font altogether.)

Comment: But in your shoes I wouldn't use both `8pt` and `\scriptsize`: the resulting text is just too small for a presentation.

Comment: Or actually you could use `\RequirePackage{fix-cm}` prior to `\documentclass...` which is what the package documentation suggests.